# list of premade docker-compose.yml configurations

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to play around with docker but configuration setup seems kind of redundant since my stack needs are pretty generic. So i'm convinced that this has been done a million times before, but i can find any resources for different docker-compose.yml files on the web. Does anybody know of any website that would have a bunch of these or maybe i'm just misunderstanding how docker works.

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filename%3Adocker-compose.yml&type=Code

Comment: @Federkun Seems you can't search that way, link doesn't work for me atleast